# how to show or hide a div on button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

here the following are the codes

```
<style type="text/css">
#mydiv{ margin:0 auto;padding:0;width:250px;height:100px; border:1px solid threedshadow;display:none;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show()
{
var div=document.getElementById('mydiv');
div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
</script>



<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="show"/>
<div id="mydiv">
```

this code does not working can anybody help me!!

Comment: Because "this code does not working can anybody help me!!" is not a problem description @Dropout

Comment: @sidhewsar be sure to close your div if you're not already: `<div id="mydiv"></div>`

Comment: @PeeHaa well.. yeah.. that's true

Comment: HTML
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="Click Me" id="myBtn"/>
<div id="mydiv">This is Div</div>

CSS:

Comment: @Peehaa 
when i was posted it without the senetence ("this code does not working can anybody help me!!") 
its show an error message It Looks Like your Post is mostly code; please add some more details. that is why i had to write that line

Comment: That a hint so that you add an actual decent question instead of a codedump. You failed to get the hint obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close, but you're not assigning the display value to the display property. Try this:

```
div.style.display = (div.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="Click Me" id="myBtn"/> 
<div id="mydiv">This is Div</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mydiv{ 
 margin:0 
 auto;padding:0;
 width:250px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid threedshadow;
 display:none;}
```

**Script:**

```
var showBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

showBtn.onclick = function() {
    var showme = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    if (showme.style.display !== 'none') {
        showme.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        showme.style.display = 'block';
    } };
```