# How to expand next section on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have the following combination of code:

index.html

```
<body>
  <div class="checkout">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cc" checked>
    <label for="cc">
        <div class="tab cc">
            <h3 class="tab__title">Credit Card<span class="fa fa-check"></span></h3>
            <div class="tab__content">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="full cc-number" placeholder="Card Number">
                    <input type="text" class="expiry" placeholder="MM / YY"><input type="text" class="cvc" placeholder="CVC">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember"><label for="remember">Remember me</label>
                    <button type="button" class="button--action button--circle">GO</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="agreement">
    <label for="agreement">
        <div class="tab agreement">
            <h3 class="tab__title">Agreement<span class="fa fa-check"></h3>
            <div class="tab__content">
                <div class="agreement__text">
                    <p>Kombucha offal kale chips semiotics, health goth shoreditch craft beer pickled occupy gentrify wayfarers franzen. Fanny pack crucifix jean shorts portland mumblecore chartreuse. Yr migas scenester, hoodie artisan fap chicharrones brunch ramps. Waistcoat venmo austin photo booth 90's affogato, viral craft beer readymade iPhone fashion axe. Cliche health goth cold-pressed cronut banjo selfies ennui synth locavore, etsy hoodie ethical. Synth everyday carry small batch, try-hard photo booth green juice tumblr farm-to-table normcore. Irony kinfolk fanny pack, beard scenester drinking vinegar asymmetrical man braid helvetica venmo chicharrones.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
... More code
```

index.js

```
(function() {
    var tabs = $('.tab');

    tabs.on('click', function(e) {
        var checkbox = $(this).parents('label').prev();

        // Fix for all tabs collapsing when click is within the area taken up by a button
        if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
            $(checkbox).prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Don't collapse the currently open tab when clicked on
        if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        // Allow only one tab to be open at a time
        checkbox.siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    });
})();
```

I also have some CSS but I don't think it is extremely relevant.
The code has different tabs and clicking in one will open it and close the one that is open. How can I make a button that opens the tab that is directly after? Each tab is

https://jsfiddle.net/x7kredj0/

Comment: Can you provide a working JSfiddle for the work you have done till now. So that it will be easier to understand and solve, than the give code.

Comment: @AKA https://jsfiddle.net/x7kredj0/

Comment: So what is your actual problem with the bottom tab?

Comment: @AKA I just want to creat button that opens the tab right after

Comment: so the button can be multiple and it is placed just before each tab. This is what you mean?

Comment: @AKA If you got to the jsfiddle and open the first tab you will see a button call Go. How can I make that button open the next tab Agreement?

Comment: @carlosremove I have used `Bootstrap Collapse` to implement this behavior. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Comment: @LiniSusanV So they have to recode the whole thing using that?

Comment: @carlosremove If you are using `Bootstrap` in your project, I would suggest you to rebuild that HTML section.

Comment: @LiniSusanV But I am not using Bootstrap, so how can I do it on my code?

Comment: Please check if you can use https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/

Comment: Please refer this existing issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001408/how-to-show-or-hide-a-div-on-button-click-using-javascript

Comment: @carlosremove i just posted a solution, hope that helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `click` function on button and some jQuery fun:

```
$('.openNext').on('click',function(e){  
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();     
 $(this).closest('label').next('input').next('label').find('h3').trigger('click');
});
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7kredj0/7/

Comment: Why doesn't your code work with this html https://jsfiddle.net/x7kredj0/6/

Comment: first fix your tab problem,tabs is not working, if i clicked on any tab and remove my code.

Comment: They do work. You just need to hit RUN after you remove your code

Comment: then this is your css issue, your tab content is `opacity:0` it should be `display:none`.

Comment: And where is that? I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution :

```
/* solution */
.tab::after {
  content:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAAOVBMVEUAAAD///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////8KOjVvAAAAEnRSTlMABQYQERQVHjthZnBzfo7p6/GnIDUbAAAAR0lEQVQYV53IORaAMAwD0QHCZjZb9z8sDc8EyqjSH2hYX/0OOGJMFz9hVZbi2gBTTAAMrh3ekn5KZTDFclUGkz4G+xlm2ncDeu4CtLEndvMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    right: 15px;
}

.checkout input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label .tab::after {
  content:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAARVBMVEUAAAD///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////9SnXPCAAAAFnRSTlMAAQIEBQYnL3+Rl56goqqrrbTFx875F1Lu/gAAAEpJREFUGFelyUkCgCAMQ9GAE+KM0vsf1SiCuJWs+l+Bv6tM820nRy5snwt7rYdX2IuGGqOERpKr1f15ZJM5NGWSHWhtbErfpbtkJ8I2AzMNzbhgAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}
```

See the result here
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7kredj0/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code as per uer need. Please try it

```js
(function() {
  var tabs = $('.tab');

  tabs.on('click', function(e) {

    var checkbox = $(this).parents('label').prev();
    // Fix for all tabs collapsing when click is within the area taken up by a button
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      $(checkbox).prop('checked', true);
    }

    // Don't collapse the currently open tab when clicked on
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Allow only one tab to be open at a time
    checkbox.siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  });

  var goBtn = $('#go-btn');
  goBtn.on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var checkbox = $('#agreement');
    $(checkbox).prop('checked', true);
    // Allow only one tab to be open at a time
    checkbox.siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  });
})();
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300, 400,700";

/*** [Colours] ***/


/*** [Resets] ***/

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #22313F;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/*** [Vars & Mixins] ***/


/*** [Menu styling] ***/

.checkout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.checkout input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

.checkout input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkout input[type="checkbox"]+label:first-of-type .tab {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.checkout input[type="checkbox"]+label:last-of-type .tab {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.checkout input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .tab {
  height: 250px;
}

.checkout input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .tab__content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.checkout input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label h3 .fa-check {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkout .tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 83.33333px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  transition: height 400ms cubic-bezier(0.72, -0.25, 0.4, 1.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.checkout .tab__content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}

.checkout .tab .text-large {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.checkout .tab__title {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.checkout .tab__title .fa-chevron-left {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.checkout .tab__title .fa-check {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}

.checkout .tab .button--action {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.5rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background: transparent;
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.checkout .tab .button--circle {
  width: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkout .tab.cc {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient:         http://colorzilla.com/gradienteditor/#a9ead6+0,9edacb+100 */
  background: #a9ead6;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #a9ead6 0%, #9edacb 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  color: #228b6b;
}

.checkout .tab.cc .input-group input[type='text'] {
  padding: 0.7rem 0.8rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #66ae98;
}

.checkout .tab.cc .input-group input[type='text'].cc-number {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.checkout .tab.cc .input-group input[type='text'].expiry {
  width: 60%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-right: 0;
}

.checkout .tab.cc .input-group input[type='text'].cvc {
  width: 40%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.checkout .tab.cc .input-group input[type='text'].expiry,
.checkout .tab.cc .input-group input[type='text'] .cvc {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkout .tab.cc .input-group input[type='text']:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.checkout .tab.cc .input-group input[type='checkbox']+label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  content: '\00a0';
  border: 1px solid #66ae98;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkout .tab.agreement {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#46cdcf+0,3fb8bf+100 */
  background: #46cdcf;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #46cdcf 0%, #3fb8bf 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  color: #1f7577;
}

.checkout .tab.agreement .tab__content {
  height: 100%;
}

.checkout .tab.agreement .agreement__text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.checkout .tab.agreement .agreement__text::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background: #1f7577;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.checkout .tab.agreement .agreement__text::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #1f7577;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.checkout .tab.payment {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#3d84a8+0,37779c+100 */
  background: #3d84a8;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #3d84a8 0%, #37779c 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  color: #a1c9dd;
}

.checkout .tab.confirmation {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#48466d+0,413f67+100 */
  background: #48466d;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #48466d 0%, #413f67 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  color: #9593b9;
}

.checkout .tab.confirmation .button--action {
  bottom: 5rem;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease;
}

.checkout .tab.confirmation .button--action.no {
  left: 1.5rem;
}

.checkout .tab.confirmation .button--action.yes {
  width: 120px;
  left: 6.5rem;
}

.checkout .tab.confirmation .button--action:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.checkout .tab.confirmation .button--action .fa {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #2b8368;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #2b8368;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #2b8368;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #2b8368;
}
```

```html
<title>Checkout Interface</title>



<div class="checkout">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cc" checked>
  <label for="cc">
    <div class="tab cc">
      <h3 class="tab__title">Credit Card<span class="fa fa-check"></span></h3>
      <div class="tab__content">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="full cc-number" placeholder="Card Number">
          <input type="text" class="expiry" placeholder="MM / YY">
          <input type="text" class="cvc" placeholder="CVC">
          <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
          <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
  <button id="go-btn" type="button" class="button--action button--circle">GO</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="agreement">
<label for="agreement">
    <div class="tab agreement">
      <h3 class="tab__title">Agreement<span class="fa fa-check"></h3>
      <div class="tab__content">
        <div class="agreement__text">
          <p>Kombucha offal kale chips semiotics, health goth shoreditch craft beer pickled occupy gentrify wayfarers franzen. Fanny pack crucifix jean shorts portland mumblecore chartreuse. Yr migas scenester, hoodie artisan fap chicharrones brunch ramps.
            Waistcoat venmo austin photo booth 90's affogato, viral craft beer readymade iPhone fashion axe. Cliche health goth cold-pressed cronut banjo selfies ennui synth locavore, etsy hoodie ethical. Synth everyday carry small batch, try-hard photo
            booth green juice tumblr farm-to-table normcore. Irony kinfolk fanny pack, beard scenester drinking vinegar asymmetrical man braid helvetica venmo chicharrones.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>

<input type="checkbox" id="payment">
<label for="payment">
    <div class="tab payment">
      <h3 class="tab__title">Payment<span class="fa fa-check"></span></h3>
      <div class="tab__content">
        <span class="text-large">$32.00</span>
        <button type="button" class="button button--action">Pay Now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>

<input type="checkbox" id="confirmation">
<label for="confirmation">
    <div class="tab confirmation">
      <h3 class="tab__title">Confirmation<span class="fa fa-check"></h3>
      <div class="tab__content">
        <p>Confirm purchase?</p>
        <button type="submit" class="button button--action yes"><span class="fa fa-check"></span>Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="button button--action no"><span class="fa fa-times"></span>No</button>
      </div>
  </label>
</div>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
```